# King of Tokyo: Poison Spit

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Poison Spit states the following:

> When you deal damage to monsters give them a poison counter. Monsters take 1 damage for each poison counter they have at the end of their turn. You can get rid of a poison counter with a [Heart] (that [Heart] doesn't heal a damage also).

What happens with counters that are healed? Are they removed from the game or are they returned to the owner of the card? The card seems overpowered in the second case, as it only costs 4 energy. (The same question for Shrink Ray)

Comment: While it CAN be very powerful, way more often than not, a poisoned person gets rid of the poison counter during the first turn after they get it. This means that the poison card just acts as +1 damage to normal damage, as it stops 1 heart from actually healing. Also do not that it's NOT 1 poison counter per damage dealt; just 1 total when you deal damage (per person).

Answer (score 6):

There isn't really a concept of them belonging to the owner.  They go back to the token pool, which is where people take them from as needed.  So they can be used again on the same or different players.

Comment: Also, the concept of tokens or energy tokens running out is foreign to the game - don't have the rules near me, but I think if you 'run out' of tokens, you just improvise other markers - there's no real limit on how many poison tokens can be on the monsters simultaneously